# How to add the source code to a LaTeX document generated with sphinx

Tags: python, latex, python-sphinx

I'm generating the docs of my python library with Sphinx. I use the extension [sphinx.ext.viewcode](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/viewcode.html)

```
extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.doctest",
    "sphinx.ext.intersphinx",
    "sphinx.ext.ifconfig",
    "sphinx.ext.viewcode",  # Add links to highlighted source code
    "sphinx.ext.napoleon",  # to render Google format docstrings
]
```

This generates a link to the source documentation, similarly to:

```
class MyClass(param1, param2)[source]
```

like in this image:

[image: screenshot]

If I press source, I see the source code correctly in my HTML page.

I would like to do exactly the same when I generate a LaTeX file. I can't find in the documentation how to add the source code when you create a pdf from LaTeX. Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to add code to python through a package called [listings](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings). This package allows one to show code and even complete files.

For implementing this, in `conf.py` you can add:

```
latex_elements = {
    "papersize": "letterpaper",
    "pointsize": "10pt",
    "figure_align": "htbp",
    "preamble": r"""
        \usepackage{listings}
        \lstset{ 
            language=Python,                 % the language of the code
            title=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
        }
    """,
}
```

there are more settings that can be added to `lstset`.

Then the code can be added in the `.rst` file as:

```
.. raw:: latex

    \section{Code}
    \lstinputlisting{../../../path/to/my/file.py}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [`sphinx.ext.viewcode`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/viewcode.html):

> This extension works only on HTML related builders like `html`, `applehelp`, `devhelp`, `htmlhelp`, `qthelp` and so on except `singlehtml`.

Comment: thanks, I saw that, however, there is no way yo add the code in latex?

Comment: There is always a way if you are prepared to do some programming... :-). I noticed that you just submitted a feature request to the Sphinx project: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/6094

Comment: @mzjn yeah, it looks there is not a good solution, which surprises me to be honest. In the past I used doxygen for C++ projects, and it worked really well, they have a solution for python http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html#pythonblocks. I think I will try to see if doxygen/python works well, if not, I'll make a script to attach the python code to sphinx/latex :-(